Computing confidence intervals for fenegbin object when predicting predicted probabilities
I would be grateful for some help computing confidence intervals for predicted probabilities of a negative binomial model estimated through fixest::fenegbin given a very large amount of fixed effects. The model looks as follows:
model <- fenegbin(CountVariable~ X1*X2|  date_fe, data = data)
summary(model)

Which I predict as follows:
# Sequence for interaction terms for plotting or predictions
X1_seq <- seq(min(data$X1, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                   max(data$X1, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                   length.out = 200)
X2_seq <- seq(min(data$X2, na.rm = TRUE), 
                            max(data$X2, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                length.out = 200)

selected_dates <- unique(data$date_fe) # Adjust as necessary

# Create a data frame for prediction
pred_data_expanded <- expand.grid(X1_seq = X1,
                                  X2_seq = X2,
                                  date_fe = selected_dates) 
 # Include this line only if date_fe is relevant

# Generate predictions and confidence intervals
preds <- predict(model, newdata = pred_data_expanded)

The problem I get is that confidence intervals cannot be computed for negative binomial models using fixest:
preds <- predict(model, newdata = pred_data_expanded, type='response', 
                 se.fit = TRUE)
Error in predict.fixest(model, newdata = pred_data_expanded, 
   type = "response",  : 
      The standard-error of the prediction is currently only available
    for OLS models, sorry.

Problem is, in my field, it is very conventional to exhibit predicted probabilities with confidence intervals, and very unconventional to exhibit them without confidence intervals. The model alone with a high statistical significance may not cut it ...
If anyone has gone through this problem before or has suggestions, I'm all ears!

By default, fenegbin uses Poisson errors. Try femlm with gaussian errors,instead, or perhaps feols. Or you can report you estimated parameters and there standard errors. That package has a vignette on the topic of standard errors.
